# how to urlencode curl messages

Tags: scripting, curl

i have script got error when curl message . i think have some problem with character "space" or other because when i tried skip space , script running normal.

this is my script :

```
#!/bin/env bash

hostname="$(hostname)"
now="$(date +'%d%h%y_%H.%M.%S')"

while IFS= read -r line; 
do
curl -X GET "http://x.x.x.x:5000/submit_fajar.php?msg=\"${line}+$line+$hostname\""
done < <(cat test.txt | strings | awk -F'|' '$4 > 100{print $1 "_" $2 "_" "please check have_many_error respond_from server" "_" $3 "_" "count", $4}')
```

when running got error :

```
+ curl -X GET 'http://x.x.x.x:5000/submit_fajar.php?msg="2019-07-20_19:42_please check have_many_error respond_from server_server busy_count 176+2019-07-20_19:42_please check have_many_error respond_from server_server busy_count 176+server"'
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
```

please help how to url encode my messages to curl.

Thanks.

Comment: See `--data-urlencode` in the `curl` manual.  Related recent other question: [Use curl parameters on bash script where some characters breaks the string](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/531277)

Comment: can be specific how to solve ? i tried this command still error , curl -G --data-urlencode "http://x.x.x.x:5000/submit_fajar.php?msg=$line"